# Filter conditions on related UserModel in custom Record

Tags: relations, models, custom-field, records, usermodel

My plugin has a custom `ResponseRecord` with relations to a `UserRecord` and `ElementRecord` as follows:

```
public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'UserRecord', 'user_id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
        'element' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'ElementRecord', 'question_id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
    );
}
```

Can I query custom fields on the user or element models when querying with `findAll()` on this custom `ResponseRecord` record? If not, is there a more efficient way than iterating through all `ResponseModel` and `UserModel`?

For example, I need to query where `user.industry` (custom text field) is 'Agriculture' and where the `ResponseRecord`'s `year` attribute is `2016`.